datefns ru locale incorrect short month name
I found that all short month name in en or de locale don't have any sign at the end but in ru locale there are (like 'янв.'). But it's kinda weird cause they are at the end of some of months but not of all ('янв.' but 'июнь'). Is there is any options in format function in date-fns to hide that dots?
I found this locale file https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/main/src/locale/ru/snapshot.md and I suppose it's incorrect translation. May be there is any options to override this file?

Looks like they have a guide for contributing to the l18n effort Beyond that, you could monkey-patch the l18n file yourself...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I came up with a solution like this
    const monthsShortNames: string[] = ['янв', 'фев', 'март', 'апр', 'май', 'июнь', 'июль', 'авг', 'сент', 'окт', 'нояб', 'дек'];
export const customRuLocale: Locale = {
  ...ru,
  localize: {
    ...ru.localize,
    month: (value, options): string=> {
      if(options?.context==='standalone'&& options?.width==='abbreviated'){
        return monthsShortNames[value] || '';
      }else {
        return ru.localize.month(value, options);
      }
    }
  },
};

so I overrided ru locale with new months names
